# User search in SP2013 provider-hosted app

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, provider-hosted-app

I have a provider-hosted app in SharePoint 2013. I am trying to create a custom search for user, based on user name (I`m not using people search). I tried with KeywordQuery, and checked out the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn554260(v=office.15).aspx), but I could not find a user by his user name.

Any help or suggestions for a different approach would be much appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
if (clientContext != null)
{
   KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);

   keywordQuery.QueryText = "DisplayName:" + searchValue + "*";

   keywordQuery.HiddenConstraints = "scope:" + "\"People\"";
   keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("AccountName");
   keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("DisplayName");
   keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("UserProfile_GUID");
   keywordQuery.SelectProperties.Add("PictureURL");

   SearchExecutor search = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
   ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> result = search.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please attach the code you are using to your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you are using People Search. I usually use REST for this, but there are analogous Properties in CSOM. You have to set the result source ID to the People Result Source. In your code above remove the `HiddenConstraints` and add

```
keywordQuery.SourceId = new Guid('B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31');
```

If you really want to emulate the results you get in People Search you should also look at `enablenicknames` and `enablephonetic`.

Also, there is no `DisplayName` property by default, so unless you created that managed property you may want to use `PreferredName`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I solved the problem using CAML, but will try out this method also.